# When is it OK to use apex:pageMessages escape=false?

Tags: visualforce, security, error, hyperlink

I want to include a hyperlink in an error message on a Visualforce page.

I read that AppExchange products will fail the security test if `apex:pageMessages escape=false` is included.

My usage is for an internal business system in a private org.  It won't be distributed anywhere.

1. Is using `escape = false` the only way to display a hyperlink in an error message?
2. Is it ok to go ahead and use this technique in my scenario since only internal devs will be able to modify it?
3. Is the restriction on AppExchange products in place to protect consumers from a malicious App?

Comment: This is a good question.  I had assumed that because everything was internal, that the exposure from escape=false was not a risk.  It is the way that Salesforce uses rich text fields displaying the rich text format on VF pages, so I would expect that there are fail safes created around it.  That being said, I would love to hear if there are in fact any security risks...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> 1 - Is using 'escape = false' the only way to display a hyperlink in an error message?

Yes, otherwise it'll display as raw HTML.

> 2 - Is it ok to go ahead and use this technique in my scenario since only internal devs will be able to modify it?

As long as the messages cannot be modified or influenced by the user, this should be okay. If the user can influence the contents of the message, you're risking an "injection attack", where a savvy user inserts code that will be executed by someone else. **This** is the reason why you're not supposed to use escape=false in normal scenarios, to protect against injection attacks.

For example, let's say you wrote this code:

```
String someValue = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('message');
ApexPages.addMessage(
  new ApexPages.Message(
    ApexPages.Severity.INFO,
    message
  )
);
```

If the user were to write something like the following in their browser:

```
/apex/somePage?message=<script>alert("Hello World")</script>
```

Then this message would display an alert when escape=false. This is innocent, but imagine a user sends a much more complicated script by email to an unsuspecting other user in the system. They could hijack the user's session, send out spam emails, change passwords, delete records, etc, whatever permissions they have, without even realizing something was wrong.

The point here is that *if* you use escape=false, you must make sure that you are using well-formed HTML, and do not allow arbitrary, unsanitized strings to reach the message, because it can be abused.

All that said... if only devs/admins can modify the messages, and there's no risk of injection, go for it. Just be aware that you should always carefully check your code to make sure that injection is not possible. Using escape=true eliminates the risk of injection, but obviously won't allow you to embed a hyperlink.

> 3 - Is the restriction on AppExchange products in place to protect consumers from a malicious App?

No, it's to protect users from apps that could be manipulated by users to hijack a user session. Apps are analyzed to see if they're malicious anyways, but this particular security vulnerability means that it's possible for user A to hijack user B's session just by modifying a record a certain way, sending an email, etc.

Even worse, if a non-user discovered this exploit, they could craft an email that has a link which, when clicked on by a user, could steal data, lock out users, etc. Injection vulnerabilities are a serious deal, so always make sure that you're only using it in a way where injection is impossible, such as using only static strings, sanitizing input using String.stripHtml4, etc.

Comment: Very comprehensive - Thank you.  In my case I am formulating a link to another VF page that includes a record Id.  No user input fields are used in the hyperlink.  Your answer reassures me that it is safe under my circumstances.